# Calling filters in django-graphene with GraphQL

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I've been following the documentation for Graphene-Python in Django, and have just made it to the section on custom filters. While a tutorial is provided for how to *write* custom filters, there isn't a reference on how to *call* them in GraphiQL. If I have the following example code:

```
class AnimalNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        # Assume you have an Animal model defined with the following fields
        model = Animal
        filter_fields = ['name', 'genus', 'is_domesticated']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class AnimalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # Do case-insensitive lookups on 'name'
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr=['iexact'])

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['name', 'genus', 'is_domesticated']

    @property  # make your own filter like this
    def qs(self):
        return super(EquityFilter, self).qs.filter(id=self.request.user)


class Query(ObjectType):
    animal = relay.Node.Field(AnimalNode)
    # We specify our custom AnimalFilter using the filterset_class param
    all_animals = DjangoFilterConnectionField(AnimalNode,
                                              filterset_class=AnimalFilter)
```

My question is, **what would I need to type in GraphiQL to use this filter**? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "use this filter"? With the code above your queries are already using the `AnimalFilter`. Are you referring to how do you specify the user in GraphiQL?

Comment: Thanks for the response @kirbuchi ,I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here. Using GraphiQL, when we applied the previous filters using a format such as `filter_fields = {'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith']}`, I would type in `query {allAnimals(name_Icontains: "lion") { edges { node { id, name }}}}` to the GraphiQL console to use the filter. My question is, what do I need to enter in the GraphiQL console to use my newly created custom filter posted in my initial question? Also, now that you mention it, how would I specify the user in GraphiQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the schema in GraphiQL. It should show a root query similar to this one:

```
allAnimals(
  before:String,
  after:String,
  firts:Int,
  last:Int,
  name:String,
  genus:String,
  isDomesticated:Boolean
):AnimalNodeConnection
```

The three filter criteria are exposed as query parameters, so you can use them with a query like this one:

```
query filteredAnimals{
  allAnimals(
    name:"Big Foot",
    genus:"Unknown",
    isDomesticated:false
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        genus
        isDomesticated
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which will give you a connection with undomesticated animals named "Big Foot" ("big FOOT", "Big foot", etc.) with genus equal to "Unknown".

**Note:** Filters declared on the `FilterSet` Meta class are named after the type of filtering they do, like `name_Icontains`, `name_Iexact`. Filters declared as `FilterSet` fields (name filter in your case) keep their names unmodified, and extend or **OVERRIDE** filters declared in the `FilterSet` Meta class.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I appreciate the help!